# Rails: after rendering partial with Ajax, manipulating that partial with JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

On my app, users click a button that makes a text field appear via ajax.

I want to focus on that text field after it appears.

`$("#my-textfield").focus()` does not work when in my js.erb file, but works fine in the console. I also tried it with a `setTimeout` to no avail.

When I do `document.getElementById('my-textfield').focus();` I get "cannot focus on null".

Do I need to "reload" the DOM somehow after loading a partial via ajax?

Comment: It might be possible that the element hasn't loaded yet. Can you try console.log($("#my-textfield").length) ?

Comment: I get 0 when I do that. But right now I'm setting a `timeout` of half a second.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the event `DOMNodeInserted` with .on(). It's not widely supported yet, and I've never used it, but it looks like it may work for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really done this but you can try

```
$function() {
  $("#my-textfield").load(function() {
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
```

to make sure it has loaded first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- tried it out but it didn't work. I think the "new" textfield that gets inserted is just not on the same plane of existence that javascript is searching, and needs to get reloaded somehow.